# How to make ZStack coordinates same as the iOS Coordinate system?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have a `ZStack` within my view with many other shapes where users can draw. I'd like for the coordinate points within the `ZStack` to be the same as if the users were drawing within the full iOS window (reference of the grid here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/CoordinateSystem.html).

Right now when a user draws within a shape the coordinates start at the top right corner of the shape meaning the actual coordinates within the full window can be 50,50 or something like that but in the `ZStack` it'll say 0,0.

How do you get the `ZStack` and all relevant `Shape` within it to render the same points as it would drawing in the full iOS window?

edit: adding image for clarity

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you wanted this

```
ZStack {
    Color.clear     // background

    // your content here

}
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
.ignoresSafeArea()
```